# Read bool from cell with ExcelDataReader

Tags: c#, excel, exceldatareader

I'm using ExcelDataReader to read XLS files and it's working fine. I am able to read file contents into a DataSet:

```
var excelDataSet = reader.AsDataSet(new ExcelDataSetConfiguration 
{
    ConfigureDataTable = (_) => new ExcelDataTableConfiguration { UseHeaderRow = true }
});
```

I then take the first table from the contents:

```
DataTable? table = excelDataSet.Tables["MyTable"];
```

And I can then loop through rows and columns with table.Rows[rowNumber][colNumber] and I read all text values except `Boolean`, which are **Yes/No** values and **checkboxes**. I get null values instead.

How can I read **Yes/No** and **checkbox** values?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there is a better way, but I was able get it to work by converting to an `int` (as behind the scenes a bool is 1 or 0) and then converted that to `bool`.

I used the reader but I imagine its the same when reading from your `datatable`.

`var bool = Convert.ToBoolean(Convert.ToInt16(reader.GetString(colIndex)))`

Comment: what if I'm not using the GetString() method but instead am using the Rows property from DataTable?

Comment: should be similar process.  Read the value as a `string` and then convert it to `int`, then to `boolean`.

Comment: I do exactly that - table.Rows[rowNumber][colNumber].ToString() and it gives me empty strings.

Comment: Ok, I see...I understood it as you were trying to get it as a `boolean` but I see I misread it.  Let me try to get a sandbox set up really quick.

Comment: Are the checkbox and yes/no controls bound to a cell in your workbook?

Comment: Can they be bound to something else? Actually, I see there's a small text field in the left top above the sheet with some variable names and it seems like the Boolean cells might have them assigned. How can I access those?

Comment: OK, I see now the values for those bool cells are in so-called defined names but I still don't know how t oread them

Comment: I was able to read the data using your method of table.Rows[rowNumber][colNumber] with excel data reader so long as the control values are bound to a cell.  Perhaps providing some additional detail in your question regarding how your excel file is set up?